# Inserting values to a vector of vectors in C++ (Graph Problem)

Tags: c++, vector, graph

So this is my code for [celebrity Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-the-celebrity/) which is a graph problem using vectors .

```
int main()
{
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  int temp;
  vector<vector<int>> arr(n,vector<int>(n,0));
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
    for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
      cin>>temp;
      arr[i].push_back(temp);
    }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     //For debugging 
{
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)        //For debugging 
    {
        cout << arr[i][j]<<" ";           //For debugging 
    }
    cout<<endl;                                 //For debugging 
}


  int indegree[n]={0},outdegree[n]={0};
  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){

    for (int j=0;j<n;j++){

      if (arr[i][j]==1){

        outdegree[i]++;
        indegree[j]++;

      }
    }
  }

  for (int i=0;i<n;i++){

    if (indegree[i]==n-1 && outdegree[i]==0){

       cout<<"Our celebrity"<<i<<endl;
       break; 
     }
     else{
       cout<<"-1"<<endl;
       break; }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This code gave me wrong answer and after debugging via printing onto the console I found that there is some problem with the vector initialisation and insertion of values to that `vector of vectors`
The output is ,

```
4    //input the value of n-which is size
0 0 1 0    
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 0     //the adjacent matrix
0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0      //debugged vector of vectors
0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 

-1          //value returned -answer whether the person is a celebrity or not
            //if not print -1
```

Here ,is the better picture of the problem.
[image]

**My Question-**
What is the mistake made in vector initialization and insertion of values ? How can I improve it ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should output the size of your matrix after the input. It's not what you think.

Comment: Since problem is just obsolete use of `push_back` voting to close a s typo. I really recommend to learn how to use debugger, the you would spot this quite fast.

Comment: @MarekR I don't know how to use one,If you can help me out with this issue.If not,thank you for voting to close down !

Answer (score 2):

The lines

```
cin>>temp;
arr[i].push_back(temp);
```

add a new element to your vector. But your vector already has the correct size and you just want to set the value:

```
cin >> arr[i][j];
```

Example for i = 0, j = 0:

Initially arr[0] is [0, 0, 0, 0]. After `arr[0].push_back(3)` it's [0, 0, 0, 0, 3]. But you want [3, 0, 0, 0]. `cin >> a[0][0]` writes the value into the correct element.